# Is there a way to perform "if" check only once instead of every iteration in a loop?

Tags: conditionals

The `\zNonZero` is equal to `0` if `#1` is `0`, but is equal to `1` if `#1` is greater than `0`. The problem is, the `if` check inside the loop is performed every iteration: I need it to be performed only once (for the first iteration). Is there a way to get rid of unneeded checks?

```
\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\newcount\zNonZero
\def\zLoop#1%
  { \zNonZero1
    \ifnum#1<1 % HOW TO CHECK THIS ONLY ONCE?
      \zNonZero0
    \fi
    \ifnum#1<5
      #1...(\the\zNonZero)\newline
      \expandafter\zLoop\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}
    \fi
  }
\zLoop{0}
\end{document}
```

The "if" check is done 5 times here, but we need it to be done only once:

[image]

Comment: Is this your real code or is your actual test more expensive? I don't think this simple test will have any performance impact even for a larger number of iterations.

Comment: You could create two separate functions. One that processes the first iteration and does the "if" check, and something that processes subsequent iterations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Detach the first conditional.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\zNonZero

\def\zLoop#1{%
  \zNonZero=1
  \zLoopStart{#1}%
  \zLoopLoop{#1}%
}
\def\zLoopStart#1{%
  \ifnum#1<1 % HOW TO CHECK THIS ONLY ONCE?
    \zNonZero=0
  \fi
}
\def\zLoopLoop#1{%
  \ifnum#1<5
    #1...(\the\zNonZero)\par
    \zNonZero=1
    \expandafter\zLoopLoop\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\expandafter\relax\expandafter}%
  \fi
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\zLoop{0}

\end{document}
```

Note the two more `\expandafter` tokens so the entire conditional is removed before the loop is restarted.

This possibly doesn't qualify, but I'll mention it anyway.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\zLoop}{m}
 {
  \bp_zloop:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \bp_zloop:n
 {
  \int_compare:nT { #1 < 5 }
   {
    #1...(\int_eval:n { \int_min:nn { #1 } { 1 } })\par
    \bp_zloop:f { \int_eval:n { #1 + 1 } }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bp_zloop:n { f }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\zLoop{0}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}    
\begin{document}
    \parindent0pt
    \newcount\zNonZero
    \newif\ifCheck \Checktrue
    \def\zLoop#1{%
        \zNonZero1
        \ifCheck\ifnum#1<1 \zNonZero0 \fi\Checkfalse\fi
        \ifnum#1<5
        #1...(\the\zNonZero)\newline
        \expandafter\zLoop\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}
        \fi
      \Checktrue
    }
    \zLoop{0}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ...this still performs a conditional check `\ifCheck` with every call of `\zLoop`.

Comment: @Werner in case the `\ifnum#1<1` is a placeholder for a test that is actually more expensive then this could actually be faster - maybe in practise it does not make a difference but at least in theory it is a good idea.